# How to select hyper parameters for SVC estimator in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm classifiying some texts with SVC and I would like to run a grid search so I followed the example provided at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html#example-grid-search-text-feature-extraction-py). In the example they are using SGDClassifier with the following parameters:

```
parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    #'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    #'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    #'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    #'clf__n_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}
```

My issue is, what kind of parameters should I try for SVC classifier, tfidf, hashing vectorizer and CountVectorizer?. How should I select this parameters if this is a multi class classification problem?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read what those parameters mean and decide for yourself.

I optimize following: 
SVC: gamma and C
TFIDF: max_features, max_df, min_df

That really depends on your data and model. If you don't know run very wide optimization on many parameters and many possible values to narrow it down.
This is time consuming so you may want to subsample your data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I realized that this will take time since when I run the gridsearch it takes a long. My data are just strings, 5 classes and 3000 instances. By subsampling the data you are refering only to pass let's say the half of the instances?. Does the parameters I'm using are right?.

Comment: Shuffle and subsample them to say 500 and run first wide parameter search. Params for vectorizer seem a bit extreme: do you really want to remove 50% of most frequent words ? I use 0.99 for max_df to remove words or ngram that exist in almost each sample. As for SGDClassifier  I don't know, I use different classifiers.

Comment: I'm using SVC, which parameters do you recommend me to test for this task?. Thanks!

Comment: C and gamma as I said earlier